# error al obtener información de tabla

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estoy utilizando Entity Framework para la consulta de información, pero cuando pasa por la variable que tengo me tira un error que dice:

> Error de servidor en la aplicación '/'. Esta solicitud se ha bloqueado
> porque no se puede revelar información confidencial en sitios web de
> terceros cuando se utiliza en una solicitud GET. Para permitir
> solicitudes GET, establezca JsonRequestBehavior en AllowGet.
> Descripción: Excepción no controlada al ejecutar la solicitud Web
> actual. Revise el seguimiento de la pila para obtener más información
> acerca del error y dónde se originó en el código.
>
> Detalles de la excepción: System.InvalidOperationException: Esta
> solicitud se ha bloqueado porque no se puede revelar información
> confidencial en sitios web de terceros cuando se utiliza en una
> solicitud GET. Para permitir solicitudes GET, establezca
> JsonRequestBehavior en AllowGet.
>
> Error de código fuente:
>
> Se ha generado una excepción no controlada durante la ejecución de la
> solicitud Web actual. La información sobre el origen y la ubicación de
> la excepción pueden identificarse utilizando la excepción del
> seguimiento de la pila siguiente.

```
ViewBag.DepartamentoAccess = db.AccessPoints.FirstOrDefault(x => x.AccessPointId == activoId).Contacto.Departamento;
```

En esta misma variable es en la que me tira una `exception` y da tira ese error.

Comment: Lectura altamente sugerida: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Especialmente punto 2 y punto 4. Saludos.

Comment: Luis... Ya intentaste la solución que te propone el framework? *Para permitir solicitudes GET, establezca JsonRequestBehavior en AllowGet.*

Comment: como establezco el allowGet?